# SQL Server function parameters

Tags: sql-server, function

I have a function that takes two parameters of type **date** like this

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Test] (@DiffFrom DATE, @DiffTo DATE) 
RETURNS INT
```

but when I try to run

```
SELECT [fn_Test](convert(date, 'Oct 23 2012 11:01AM') ,  GETDATE())
```

I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How can we debug your function if you haven't posted it -_-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to qualify the function name like this:

```
SELECT [dbo].[fn_Test](convert(date, 'Oct 23 2012 11:01AM') ,  GETDATE())
```